# Javascript - code and decode from base64 using atob() and btoa() functions

Tags: javascript, base64

I am trying some simple code - decode logic using the standard browser functionalities `atob()` and `btoa()` and I am encountering behaviors I can not fully understand.

I have written a very simple test case

```
 it('converts from base64 to ascii', () => {
    const stringA = 'I am Enrico in Asci';
    const stringB = atob(stringA);
    const stringA1 = btoa(stringB);
    console.log('My ASCCI to binary and viceversa', stringA1);
    expect(stringA1).toBe(stringA);
  });
```

The test case fails. What I see on the console of Chrome is

```
Expected 'IamEnricoinAscg=' to be 'I am Enrico in Asci'.
```

Apparently all spaces have gone and end character is wrong. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You've got your `atob` and `btoa` the wrong way round.  stringB use `btoa` and stringA1 use `atob`... And easy way to remember, think the source as always been binary, even if a string..  Or another way of thinking of it,  A = Encoded Base64,  B = The Data.   Stupid names for Base64 encoding I know..

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. I was stupidly imagining that `atob` ascii to base64 and viceversa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it in the proper order ;)

```js
    const stringA = 'I am Enrico in Asci';
    const stringB = btoa(stringA);
    const stringA1 = atob(stringB);
    console.log('stringA', stringA);
    console.log('stringA1', stringA1);
    console.log('equals', stringA === stringA1);
```

Comment: `btoa` give a longer string, so the proper order is to first use `atob` and handle (send, download, store) shorter strings.

Answer (score 0):

There is two problems to solve!

1. The `atob()` decodes ascii to bytes, where ascii is restricted to six bits, that is Base64. Four six-bit Base64 characters fit exactly into three eight-bit bytes. If it is not a multiple of four the input has to be padded with `/` characters. You then simply trim the `/` characters from the output of `btoa()`. To pad with `=` is not allowed in `atob()`, because the parameter has to be Base64 and that character is not included.
2. The `atob()` function in JavaScript remove spaces from the input string because Base64 encoding does not support spaces. Allowed characters are `A`-`Z`, `a`-`z`, `0`-`9`, `+`, and `/`. So you can replace the spaces by `+` and replace it back to space after all is done.

**Solution**

```js
const stringA = 'I am Enrico in Asci';

//% = modulo = remainder of division by 4. 
//Fill the rest to add up to a group of 4.
const pads = "///".slice(0, 4 - stringA.length % 4);

//replace illegal characters by '+' and add pads.
const stringB = atob(stringA.replaceAll(' ', '+') + pads);
const stringA1 = btoa(stringB);

//replace all '+' and '/' back to ' ' and trim.
const stringA2 = stringA1.replaceAll(/[+\/]/g, ' ').trim();
console.log(stringA === stringA2);
```

You have to replace illegal characters by `+`. If you have more than one illegal character you need to send two strings. The second string then has legal Base64 characters for each `+` to be replaced with its illegal character mapped to those legal Base64 characters (that are indexes into a decoding string). In that way you can have 62 characters more.

Answer (score -4):

```
const stringA1 = btoa(stringB);
```

you define constant , there must be var

```
var stringA1 = btoa(stringB);
```

Comment: A string is always constant in Javascript. It can't be changed by indexing. For safety we use `const` when the string is not meant to be replaced.